# How to take string as input and output each letter of the string on a new line, repeated N times, where N is the position of the letter in the string

Tags: python

I was given this problem in a Python class I'm taking.
Take a string as input and output each letter of the string on a new line, repeated N times, where N is the position of the letter in the string.

Here is my first attempt:

```
string = input()

for i in string:
    n = string.index(i) + 1
    print(i * n)
```

'''

but the output for the input: 'awesome', was:

'''

```
a
ww
eee
ssss
ooooo
mmmmmm
eee
```

'''

The output I want is:

'''

```
a
ww
eee
ssss
ooooo
mmmmmm
eeeeeee
```

'''

I was able to figure out a different way of doing it, that ended up giving me the correct output:

```
string = input()
i = 0
while i < len(string):
    
    print(string[i] * (i + 1))
    i += 1

a
ww
eee
ssss
ooooo
mmmmmm
eeeeeee
```

My question now is why my first attempt does not give me the expected output.

Comment: If you want the index in a for loop, use `for index, elem in enumerate(sequence)`

Comment: *"My question now is why my first attempt does not give me the expected output"* - the answer is in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) - *"index of __the first__ occurrence of x in s"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

`string.index(i)` returns the *first* index of `i`, which is simply the letter e in this case (when you call `string.index('e')`, Python doesn't know you've obtained `'e'` as the x'th letter from the same string).